# How to remove window title from Jump Bar in Xcode 5 while in fullscreen

Tags: xcode, macos, fullscreen

I've searched far and wide with no results on Google. I also looked through all of Xcode's Preferences and even tried dragging it off but does nothing but move the window inside of itself while in full screen mode.

So, here's my question: How do I remove, or at least move, the window title off of the jump bar so I can actually use it in full screen mode? Xcode 5, OS X Yosemite.

Here is what I'm seeing.
[image: Example]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Xcode 5 rather than Xcode 6?

Comment: No longer have a dedicated network to download Xcode 6 since I moved, so now I'm strictly LTE.